# Who owns or controls the Atacama Desert?

Tags: real-estate, chile

This question arose from a discussion about colonising Mars. Clearly if you can live on Mars then the Atacama Desert should be a cinche. So that leads to the question of who owns it. The bulk is in Chile. I know that there are some towns, and a bunch of abandoned mines that may belong to someone, but what about the rest of it?

Suppose a few hundred settlers started erecting domes and polytunnels somewhere in the middle of the desert. Who would have the legal right to object? Government? Indigenous peoples? Is it a National Park? Or is it terra nullis?

Comment: You should narrow this down a bit, e.g. specify "the part in Chile", "not in Los Flamencos Nat'l Reverse", "not in downtown Socaire" or "not in the middle of Campamento Andino mining operation".

Comment: I was under the impression that the entire Atacama Desert is entirely in Chile, in the same way that the Mojave is entirely in the US, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @user6726 I'm interested in the bulk of the desert, rather than small bits of mining concessions and the like. So if 30% is a national park then that's relevant.

Comment: This is not a legal question. “Who” owns it is a matter of record not law. “Who” can objectively is trivially the owner.

Comment: It's mainly a question about Chilean law and land ownership. Obviously you have to *exclude* the privately-owned chunks like Socaire etc. What remains is the analog of homesteading law in Chile.

Comment: @user6726 and the OP can ask a question about that if they like. This question is analogous to “Who owns Santiago?”

Comment: @DaleM "the analog of homesteading law" is the kind of thing I'm trying to find out about. I don't know if the bulk of the desert is owned by a particular entity, or if it is a national park, or collectively owned by indigenous peoples under a particular legal framework, or if you can homestead it. Saying the owner can object is only a useful answer if there is in fact an owner. The answer might be different for different parts, in which case the different legal frameworks would be useful (e.g. some is private property, some is tribal land...)

Comment: OK, this is embarrassing. Rather than trying to get this question reopened I asked a better question here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61143/homesteading-law-in-the-atacama-desert which is more focussed on what I actually want to know. I'm going to vote to re-close this as a dupe.