# Homesteading law in the Atacama Desert

Tags: real-estate, chile

This is a second attempt at [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61133/who-owns-or-controls-the-atacama-desert?noredirect=1#comment127701_61133).

Does Chile have a [homesteading law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestead_Acts)?

If so, does the [Atacama Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Desert) contain land where this could be used; i.e. not owned by anyone and not under other legal constraints (such as being a national park or tribal lands) that would prevent anyone building a homestead?

Comment: According to [this law review article](https://content.next.westlaw.com/Document/Ie8669a6fdf7611e498db8b09b4f043e0/View/FullText.html?contextData=(sc.Default)&transitionType=Default&firstPage=true), "under Decree Law No. 1939 of 1977, state property can only be sold through a strict procedure. Article 85 specifies that the sale price of state property must be at least its commercial value, as determined by a Special Commission of Disposals."  I suppose it's possible that "homesteading" is legally distinct from buying the land from the government, though, so I wouldn't view this as definitive.

Comment: As far as I know, the US s the only country tha has homestading laws.